# An explicit bijection between $\mathbb{Q}^+$ and $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was trying to show that $\vert \mathbb{Q}^+\vert=\vert \mathbb{Q}\vert$. An injection is so easy to find, but I’m having amhard time finding a surjection. Also, I don’t think there’s a similar question on stackexchange now...

Comment: Is $0 \in \Bbb{Q}^+$?

Comment: @user759562 Sorry I didn’t make it clear. Let’s say $0\notin\mathbb{Q}^+$ in this question.

Comment: If you only need to show that $|\mathbb{Q}^+| = |\mathbb{Q}|$, you don't need an explicit bijection. You can just find an injection from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}^+$ (not saying it's easy to find, but it's probably easier than an explicit bijection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, we will define $\mathbb{Q}^+:=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}:x\ge 0\}$.

One explicit bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^+$ is:
$$f(q)=\begin{cases}
2\lfloor q\rfloor+\text{frac}(q)&\lfloor q\rfloor\ge0\\
-2\lfloor q\rfloor -1+\text{frac}(q)&\lfloor q\rfloor<0\\
\end{cases}$$

This function, if restricted to $\mathbb{Q}$, defines a bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^+$ and if restricted to $\mathbb{Z}$ a bijection $\mathbb{Z}\leftrightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

More generally, given a bijection $g:\mathbb{Z}\leftrightarrow \mathbb{N}$, we can extend it to $\hat{g}:\mathbb{R}\leftrightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ by
$$\hat{g}(x)=g(\lfloor x \rfloor )+\text{frac}(x)
$$ and this extension induces a bijection $\hat{g}_{|\mathbb{Q}}:\mathbb{Q}\leftrightarrow \mathbb{Q}^+$

**Note**: however  to prove $|\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{Q}^+|$, you do not need to  find an explicit bijection. In fact, thanks to the [Schroder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem?wprov=sfla1) it suffices to show an injection $\mathbb{Q}^+\to \mathbb{Q}$ and viceversa.

Comment: To clarify my notation: $0\in \mathbb{N};\text{frac}(x)=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a neat closed form for such a bijection. However, if one has a bijection between $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $\mathbb Q$ and another bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q^+,$ then one can let the $n$ number in one list correspond to the $n$ number in the other list, and that's a bijection between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q^+.$

And if one has a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Q,$ then one can omit the terms that are not in $\mathbb Q^+$ to get a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Q^+.$

Thus once we have a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Q,$ we're there.

Look at $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb N.$ Consider the set of fractions $$S_\ell=\left\{ \frac k n : (k,n)\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb N\ \&\ \max\{|k|,n\}= \ell \right\}.$$ For example, $$S_5 = \left\{ \frac 5 1, \frac 5 2, \frac 5 3, \frac 5 4, \frac 5 5, \frac 4 5, \frac 3 5, \frac 2 5, \frac 1 5, \frac 0 5, \frac{-1}5, \frac{-2}5, \frac{-3}5, \frac{-4}5, \frac{-5}5, \frac{-5}4, \frac{-5}3, \frac{-5}2, \frac{-5}1 \right\}.$$

Discard all members that are not in lowest terms (in this case only $\pm5/5$ and $0/5$), getting a set which let us call $T_\ell.$

Now observe that $\mathbb Q=\bigcup\limits_{\ell=1}^\infty T_\ell.$ It should quickly become clear that there is a bijection from $\mathbb N$ into this union, even if there is no neat algebraic formula for it.